# Rendering html using Struts2

Tags: struts2

Using Struts2, my goal is to present a simple blog to a user using Struts2 iterators, such as:

Most Recent Topic

- response 1
- response 2
- ...

Previous Topic

- response 1
- response 2
- ...

Users generate and submit each Topic/Response using a separate form, but, once submitted, I don't want them to edit the blog.

To generate either a Topic or a Response, I provide an editor (like the stackoverflow editor I'm using now) that produces html-formatted text, including whatever styling (bold, underlines, lists, etc.) that the user chooses. The text of the Topic/Response created by the user, including the html tags, is stored in a database.

However, I cannot find a way to render the Topic/Response as html in the blog. For example, **text** bolded in the editor shows up as `<strong>text</strong>` in a struts2 s:textarea tag.

I know that the s:property tag has an 'escapeHtml' attribute that will prevent this, but the s:property tag can't layout the text properly, and it seems that only the s:property tag has this attribute.

I've tried using `<input value="%{#topic.content}" />` within the iterator instead of s:textarea, but it doesn't seem to recognize the #topic iteration reference.

Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

How about using `<pre>` with `<s:property>`.

About html `<pre>` tag:
http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_pre.asp

Comment: I don't understand what you're suggesting, although I'll research <pre> in association with the s:property tag.

Answer (score 0):

use text instated of tax area .Let me know if you still facing this issue.

Comment: That makes no sense; it's still going to show the HTML markup.

Answer (score 0):

Use escapeHtml="false". I just tried it myself and it works as intended.
For example, with:

```
<s:set var="var1"><p>some stuff</p><p>other stuff</p></s:set>

<s:property value="var1" escapeHtml="false" />
```

renders the paragraph tags as you would expect.